# How to say "I'd rather" in past tense?

Tags: grammar

1. I’d rather you stayed at home tonight.

How to say this in the past tense?  Bear in mind I want to make the "I'd rather" clause in the past. Which one of the following is correct?

1a) I'd ***rather have*** you stayed at home tonight.

or

1b) I'd ***have rather*** you stayed at home tonight.

Comment: "I'd rather you had stayed home tonight."

Comment: I want to make the "I'd rather" part in the past tense which obviously would have a different meaning than what you wrote.

Comment: "I'd rather" isn't a clause because "rather" isn't a verb, so it cannot have *any* tense. But you can do it with "prefer" because that's a verb: "*I'd have preferred you stayed home tonight.*"

Comment: Something yukky like "I'd've rathered".  ('I would have' if not dialogue.)  But if it goes in the past, 'tonight' doesn't work - 'last night' is more contextual.  Are you trying to get 'rather' in the past, while the staying (or otherwise) happens in the future?  gotube is probably correct about the whole 'rather is not a verb' thing, but that doesn't stop native speakers using it that way.   :-)

Comment: OP, people simply don't use rather that way (AmE); you are asking for something that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rather odd question.   The clause is already marked for the past tense.

Granted, it doesn't express the past tense.   Rather, it expresses something that is traditionally called *the subjunctive mode.*   Still, there are only two verbs in the sentence, a contracted "would" in the matrix and "stayed" in the content clause.   These are already the past-tense forms of *will* and *to stay*.   Neither one is a present-tense verb that you could convert to a past-tense form.

In standard English, "rather" isn't a verb.   We can't use it to place past-tense semantics into the subjunctive clause.   One way to get close to what you want is to abandon that word and instead use a verb that carries close to the same meaning:

> I would have preferred that you stayed at home tonight.

Here, the perfect-aspect construction implies a past-tense interpretation for the subjunctive-mode clause.